# How to send a parameterized DELETE to MySql from Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to delete from a table called `PersonnelTable` in the following way :

```
public void verifyDetailsBeforeClosingAccount(String _idNumber,String _username,String _password ,String _account)
{

    String retrievedNumberAccount = null;
    String retrievedOwnerIdnumber = null;

    try
    {

        // take all the rows with "account-number" and "id-numbder" in the "Checking-account-table" 

        ResultSet results = this.m_statement.executeQuery("SELECT `AccountNumber`, `IdNumber`  FROM `CheckingAccountsTable`");  
        while (results.next() == true)
        {
            retrievedNumberAccount = results.getString("AccountNumber");  // take the account number 
            retrievedOwnerIdnumber = results.getString("IdNumber");       // take the ID number 

            if (retrievedNumberAccount.equals(_account) == true && retrievedOwnerIdnumber.equals(_idNumber) == true )  // found a partial match 
            {
                // put something here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to delete a line in `PersonnelTable` , where:

1. `Password` column in the table equals the `_password` given to the function ,
2. `UserName` column in the table equals the _`username`given to the function .

That doesn't work :

```
this.m_statement.executeQuery("DELETE FROM `PersonnelTable` WHERE `Password` = _password AND `UserName` =_username ");
```

I've looked at the tutorials of `DELETE` but nothing showed how to deal with given values into a function . How can I fix this ?

Regards

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing is to delete the record whose username is "_username" (not the value that is passed to you, but literally, "_username")

You have to either:

a) Pass the value instead of the name of the variable:

```
 statement.executeQuery("DELETE FROM `PersonnelTable` WHERE `Password` = `" + _password + "` AND `UserName` = `" + _username + "` ");
```

b) Use a PreparedStatement (recommended for avoiding SQL injection attacks).

Edit: on a side note, if username is a key (unique identifier) of the register, adding the check of the password only slows the operation, complicates procedure (what if someone concurrently changes the password?) and gives you no advantage.

Comment: I'd heavily want to emphasize that `b` is definitely the option to go for. Always. Prepared statements are your friends, use them. Also, please use the same pattern for selecting your first result set, you *really, really* don't need to get the whole table and loop through it yourself to look for a match!

Comment: Isn't ` the DB object delimiter in mysql and ' the string literal delimiter?

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni it might be, it has been a long time since I have used MySQL (now I go with JPA). Feel free to correct it if you are sure of the right syntax.

Answer (score 9):

Wrap the values with single quotes because it's a string. Right?

```
this.m_statement.executeQuery("DELETE FROM `PersonnelTable` 
                               WHERE `Password` = '" + _password + "' AND 
                                     `UserName` = '" + _username + "' ");
```

much better **[Java Prepared Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)** for this.

ex

```
string sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM `PersonnelTable` 
                                   WHERE `Password` = ? AND 
                                         `UserName` = ? ";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
pstmt.setString(1, _password)
pstmt.setString(2, _username)
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a prepared statement and pass the values as parameters.

```
 String deleteString = "DELETE FROM `PersonnelTable` WHERE `Password` = ? AND `UserName` = ? ";

 PreparedStatement deleteStmt = con.prepareStatement(deleteString);

 deleteStmt.setString(1, _password);  // Use whatever the object type of user/password are
 deleteStmt.setString(2, _username);

 deleteStmt.executeUpdate();
 con.commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are sending the literal values _password and _username into your SQL; you instead need to pass the values in the variables. I would suggest doing so as parameters. My JDBC is super rusty, so you get this as a "proper code example goes here" stub for the moment.

```
 this.m_statement.executeQuery("DELETE FROM `PersonnelTable` WHERE `Password` = '" + _password + "' AND `UserName` = '"+_username +"'"); // THIS IS BAD -- but it will usually do what you are after if you need it *RIGHT NOW*
```

as other answers state, you should use PreparedStatement and parameterized queries for safety.

Answer (score 3):

You could use PrepareStatement and it's setString() method to set the _password and _username. You should not try to directly set _password and _username. When you use the setString() method, replace the variables of _password and _username in the SQL statement with '?' and do setString(1, _password) and setString(2, _username) so that the first variable would be the password variable and second variable is the username variable.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried this?

this.m_statement.executeQuery("DELETE FROM `PersonnelTable` WHERE `Password` = "+_password+" AND `UserName` ="+_username);

Comment: injecting the function parameters into the query so that `Password`=MYPASSWORD is part of the executed query?